# Drill to C source code definition when in a Python file (VSCode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, shared-libraries

I want to navigate to the definition of modules implemented in C from my Python file.

VSCode can drill to the definitions of my python objects.  Some are found automatically, while others, I need to point to.

To add additional locations I add the following to my user VSCode settings:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "C:/Users/me/Desktop/external_python"
],
```

This works fine and I can right click on objects and 'Go To Definition'.

I want to drill even further; into the C implementation.  Now, python modules implemented in C are compiled.  However, I have access to the *.h and *.c files which generated the shared objects.  So, theoretically, I could jump from my python files into .h/.c files of C from within VSCode

Is it possible to navigate from a python file into the source code of a compiled module?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for reading.  I updated but it still might not be clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possibly to drill down from the Python code to the matching C code via definition. Visual Studio may provide such functionality, but since VS Code lacks any direct ties to the object files there's no way to do the reverse lookup from Python name, to object file, to original source.